# how to rename machine in domain correctly?

Tags: c#, windows, active-directory

my c# app executes this code

```cs
...
if (!SetComputerNameW(newName)) return GetLastError();
if (!(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(adlogin) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(adpass))) {
    if (NetInDomain) return NetRenameMachineInDomain(null, newName, adlogin, adpass, NetJoinDomainOptions.NETSETUP_ACCT_CREATE); //here error 1210
    else return NetJoinDomain(null, "myorg.local", null, "myorg\\" + adlogin, adpass,
            NetJoinDomainOptions.NETSETUP_JOIN_DOMAIN | NetJoinDomainOptions.NETSETUP_ACCT_CREATE |
            NetJoinDomainOptions.NETSETUP_DOMAIN_JOIN_IF_JOINED | NetJoinDomainOptions.NETSETUP_JOIN_WITH_NEW_NAME);
...
```

local computer name changes successfully, but I have ERROR_INVALID_COMPUTERNAME at `NetRenameMachineInDomain`
[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmjoin/nf-lmjoin-netrenamemachineindomain) says nothing about it 
also currently no machine to test join domain operation, so Im not sure that using function is correct

Comment: MSDN does say something about it: *or one of the system error codes*

Comment: `newName` contains correct string, tested with "ABCABC", `SetComputerNameW` imported with `Charset=Charset.Unicode`